# Mail is not working in joomla?

Tags: php, email, joomla

Here is joomla code about send and receive mail:

```
$mailSender = JFactory::getMailer();
$mailSender->addRecipient($mailSender->From);

$mailSender->setSubject($subject);
$mailSender->setBody($body);
$mailSender->isHtml(1);

if ($mailSender->Send() !== true) {
    echo "Send Fail";
} else {
    echo "Send Success";
}
```

But it didn't work when I send and receive mail. When I send mail, it output "Send Fail". What're my problems? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please first check that is Mail function working in your site.
And if not then try using SMTP, as I faced the same issue and because my server did not provided me the mailing functionality. So, I switched to SMTP mail functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, try changing this:

```
$mailSender->isHtml(1);
```

to this:

```
$mailSender->isHtml(true);
```

---

Also, I don't think you should be using `$mailSender->From`. Instead, define your recipient(s) manually, like so:

**Single:**

```
$mailSender->addRecipient('person1@domain.com');
```

**Multiple:**

```
$recipient = array('person1@domain.com', 'person2@domain.com');
$mailSender->addRecipient($recipient);
```

---

You also need to set the sender. To do this, use the following:

```
$mailSender->setSender('youremail@example.com');
```

Comment: My new code: $mailSender = JFactory::getMailer();
$mailSender->addRecipient("contact@mydomain.com");
$mailSender->setSender("myemail@gmail.com");
$mailSender->setSubject($subject);
$mailSender->setBody($message);
$mailSender->isHtml(true);

if ($mailSender->Send() !== true) {
 echo "Send Fail";
} else {
 echo "Send Success";
} But it is not working.

Comment: Please update your question with any new code. Rather than simply saying it's "not working", try debugging it using [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

Comment: My problem: I can't send mail or receive mail when i use this code :D

Comment: Yes, and what I'm saying is, please do some debugging rather than simply saying "it's not working". It could be various reason. Have you read the Joomla documentation on how to JMail in extensions? Did you trying using `var_dump()` as I suggested?